# Multiple Models Across A Layout in CakePHP

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

What is the best way to achieve the following in CakePHP?

I have a layout which like many others has 3 major sections, a header, a footer and the main content. The header and footer aren't completely static and are implemented as Elements, it has hit counts and some other dynamic stuff. This dynamic stuff isn't related to the main content in any way but is more related to the overall site.

For this I think the footer needs to have a model of its own, can I have the footer run on a different controller/action than the main content? Else, I guess I would need to put the footer model in the main `view`'s model and than pass to the footer `element`, which doesn't seem the neatest way.

To put it in different words, the header, the footer, the main content and possibly a few more sidebars are totally independent of each other, but are rendered from the same layout. The model that is passed from the controller to the view/layout would need to have the models needed for the header/footer/content/sidebars?

I explored and found that `requestAction` might be a way, but did not convinced if that's the best way. May be I haven't looked at the right places yet.

Comment: What do you mean by `a model of its own`? What's the link between your HTML layout and your Models?

Comment: @Holt I mean the footer renders number of visits, so for it the model should ideally just be this number. Whereas the main content does not care about page visits, yet one would be required to add the visit count as a part of the model returned from the controller to the layout. I am sorry, if I am not making sense :|

Comment: Could it be that you are misunderstanding the concept of how models and views should be separated? It sounds as if you are actually passing model objects to your views?

Comment: @ndm may be, any place you suggest for me to start with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add what you need inside the `beforeRender` method of your `AppController`:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public function beforeRender () {
        $this->set('number_of_visists', /* ... */) ;
    }

} ;
```

So you'll get the value on each page, then you can either put everything inside your layout file or split it in multiple element but you'll have access to `$number_of_visits` everywhere.

---

**Edit:** Little edit to answer your comment. This is one way of doing what you want, may be not the most "correct" but the first which came to my mind. I didn't test this so it may contains some mistakes...

You could use components: Let's say you have three component, one for the header, one for the footer and one for the menu.

In your `AppController`:

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array('Header', 'Menu', 'Footer');

} ;
```

Then your components (I'll show only one example):

```
class FooterComponent extends Component {
    public function beforeRender(Controller $controller) {
        $visitModel = ClassRegistry::init('VisitCounter');
        $controller->set('number_of_visits', $visitModel->getNumberOfVisits()) ;
    }
}
```

Then in your layout you just use elements:"

```
<html>
   <!-- Whatever you want... -->
   <?php echo $this->element('footer') ; ?>
</html>
```

Every developper can work on his own component (and the associated models) and his own element without disturbing the other ones.

Comment: this does solve my prime concern, thanks! Is there any way of having a truly composite layout, say 3 different developers develop three independent widgets, each widget having its own M, V & C. and the layout being able to just compose them?

Comment: @JugalThakkar Edited my post, maybe not the better way but the first which came in my mind, hope it'll help you.